# issues running selenium tests in microsoft edge

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

What are the desired capabilities that we should set to run selenium tests in Microsoft Edge?

I am not able to click on elements at all.
I am not able to open a clean session every time the test starts.

Are there desired capabilities like nativeEvents that we need to set for Microsoft edge to get it working with selenium tests?

Answer (score 0):

For clean session (I know it sounds ridiculous but don't blame me haha) -> Edge -> Options -> Clear browsing data -> Always clear this when I close the browser -> turn it on

As for the capabilities not any specific but I use the following:

```
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.IsJavaScriptEnabled, true);  
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.HandlesAlerts, true);            
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.HasNativeEvents, true);
```